# ICSharpEditor and Accidental Hotkeys

Tags: c#, vb.net

I seem to have a bit of a problem with the ICShartEditor text editor. It works fine for me in a Windows Forms app, except that if I have a button (or any other control) on the same form that defines a hotkey (like ALT-S for a Save button), then whenever I try to type 'S' in the text editor (or whatever the hotkey might be), then it triggers the hotkey rather than adding the character to the text.

What appears to be happening under the hood is that all the ProcessMnemonic() methods for all controls of the form run, so those methods kick in and handle the keypress, which I would think should only happen if a key like the ALT-key is pressed.

Has anyone seen that behavior before? Any workarounds or fixes?

Answer (score 0):

The .Net form doesn't implement Mnemonics the way many people think it should.
One answer is to override the ProcessMnemonic in the form, and block it from being called unless the user is pressing the Alt key.

Just add this to your form class:

```
protected override bool ProcessMnemonic(char inputChar)
{
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
        return base.ProcessMnemonic(inputChar);
    return false;
}
```